# `ls / | wc -l` tells more lines than `ls /` shows

Tags: ls, wc

`ls /` outputs two lines.

```
$ ls / 
bin   cdrom  etc   initrd.img      lib    lost+found  mnt  proc  run   share  sys  usr  vmlinuz
boot  dev    home  initrd.img.old  lib64  media       opt  root  sbin  srv    tmp  var  vmlinuz.old
```

But why does `ls / | wc -l` tell 26 lines?

```
$ ls / | wc -l
26
```

Comment: I think this has to deal with ncurses library because if I do it in a xterm and readjust the window size then the number of lines that appear is different.

Answer (score 2):

As [POSIX define](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html#tag_20_73_10), `ls` will output one entry per line if output is not a terminal, or one of `-C`, `-m`, `-x` was used.

When output is terminal, the output format is implementation-defined.

[OSX ls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) and [FreeBSD ls](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls) use `-1` as default option when output is not to a terminal

Comment: Thanks. What does "output is not a terminal" mean? Is a terminal emulator such as gnome terminal emulator not a terminal?

Comment: @Tim: Yes, you can read more about it [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/38906). In your example, output of `ls` is a pipe, not a terminal.